# I am trying to compere 4 numbers within one if. Is there any particular reason my code is not working right?

Tags: c, if-statement

I am trying to make a simple if() to tell if numbers are the same. Why is my code returning false? I save numbers in double.

```
scanf("%lf %lf", &aa, &aa2);
scanf("%lf %lf", &bb, &bb2);
scanf("%lf %lf", &cc, &cc2);

if((aa == bb || aa2 == bb2) && (aa == cc || aa2 == cc2)
{
//true
}
else
{
//false
}
```

my inputs are:

```
aa = 1
aa2 = 1

bb = 2
bb2 = 2

cc = 1
cc2 = 1
```

Comment: What is your definition of "working right?"... (Apart from a missing parenthesis...)

Comment: Your code returns false because `aa != bb` and `aa2 != bb2`.   So `cc` and `cc2` don't even matter. Maybe you need to change the `&&` to `||`, and the `||`s to `&&`s.

Comment: @Fe2O3 well I want it to return true, because aa == cc and aa2 == cc2, but the code stops on the first condition.

Comment: You're saying you want to return true if the left comparisons (a/b) are true **OR** the right comparisons (a/c) are true... Sometimes it's good to _read aloud_ the expression, s-l-o-w-l-y, paying careful attention to what you are reading/saying...

Comment: @user3386109 But why?  (false || false) && (true || true) so the first is false and the second is true? Is there a way of making it work?

Comment: Yes, `x && y` is only true if both `x` AND `y` are true. If you want `x` OR `y` then it's `if (aa == bb || aa2 == bb2 || aa == cc || aa == cc2)`. Then the whole statement is true if any of the four conditions is true.

Comment: @user3386109 Oh wait? I swapped them? Okay sorry for asking this stupid question I didnt even realised that. Spent like 15 minutes of looking around.... Its working now.

Comment: Ok good, glad to hear that you got it working :)